# How to show that the transformation $T: M_{2\times 2}(R)\to M_{2\times 2}(R)$ is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

How to show that the transformation $T: M_{2\times 2}(R)\to M_{2\times 2}(R)$ is linear?

$T: M_{2\times 2}(R)\to M_{2\times 2}(R)$ is given as

$$T(M)= 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}M - M \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

How do I go about showing that it is linear?
I know that to show a transformation is linear, I need to show

1. $T(c \overrightarrow{u}) = cT(\overrightarrow{u})$
2. $T( \overrightarrow{u} + \overrightarrow{v}) = T(\overrightarrow{u})+ T(\overrightarrow{v})$

I started by saying $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}=A$,

$T(M)= AM-MA,$

and that $T(M_1 + M_2)= T(M_1)+T(M_2) = (A M_1-M_1 A)+(A M_2-M_2 A).$

How would I continue, assuming I even started off correctly?

Edit: My new steps involve $T(M_1+M_2) = A(M_1+M_2)-(M_1+M_2)A = (AM_1+AM_2)-(M_1A+M_2A)$

But I can't find which matrix operation properties would allow me to turn that into $(AM_1-M_1A)+(AM_2-M_2A)$

Comment: $T(M_1)+T(M_2)=(AM_1-M_1A)+(AM_2-M_2A)=A(M_1+M_2)-(M_1+M_2)A=T(M_1+M_2)$

Comment: You shouldn't start by saying $T(M_1+M_2)=T(M_1)+T(M_2)$; that's what you want to prove.  And cf. [commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator)

Comment: note that matrix addition (but not multiplication!) is generally commutative